# PyQt Update Child Widget Property

Tags: pyqt

I would like to update a TextBrowser widget in another window from the main window. The goal is to simply write strings to the widget to act as a pseudo console. When I inspect the QTextBrowser object, I can see that it supports `setText()` -- but I can not find a way to access `setText()` from the main window object (which I suspect is because I'm not calling it properly). Using a TextBrowser widget is not a requirement.

The examples I've seen talk about using signals and slots for such operations but that seems to be overkill for what I'm trying to accomplish. Is it a requirement to use signals for something so simple, or can I somehow `setText()` (or something similar) from the main window?

[image: Simple UI with Second Dialog]

#### scratch.py

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys

from log_dialog import Ui_dialog

class Application(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Application, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.show()

        # ===================================================
        self.log_widget = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        ui = Ui_dialog()
        ui.setupUi(self.log_widget)
        self.log_widget.exec_()

        # Write some text to log_widget  <-----

        # ===================================================

qApp = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
application_window = Application()
sys.exit(qApp.exec_())
```

#### log_dialog.py

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'log_dialog.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.3
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, dialog):
        dialog.setObjectName("dialog")
        dialog.resize(398, 307)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(dialog.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        dialog.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(dialog)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(9, 9, 381, 291))
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")

        self.retranslateUi(dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("dialog", "Log"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_dialog()
    ui.setupUi(dialog)
    dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All objects created by the "form class" (the `Ui_dialog`) are members of that form class instance.

If you look at the `setupUi()` code, you'll see that all widgets are created as members of the `Ui_dialog` class instance (`self.textBrowser`, etc).
Since `ui` is the instance, `self.someObject` becomes accessible as `ui.someObject`.

```
    ui = Ui_dialog()
    ui.setupUi(self.log_widget)
    ui.textBrowser.setText('Hello there!')
    self.log_widget.exec_()
```

For very simple situations this could be fine, but using the ui "form class" as a standalone object is usually not very convenient, especially if you're not creating a persistent reference to the ui: in your case as soon as the `__init__` of the main window returns (when the dialog is closed), you won't have have no more reference to the `ui`, as it's just an unreferenced variable that exists only within the scope of `__init__`.
Nonetheless, you will still be able to access the dialog and execute it again, and the only way to access any of its children is through:

```
self.log_widget.findChild(QtWidgets.QTextBrowser, 'textBrowser')
```

Not very convenient, uh?

A possibility is to make the ui a member of the dialog instance:

```
    self.log_widget.ui = Ui_dialog()
    self.log_widget.ui.setupUi(self.log_widget)
    self.log_widget.ui.textBrowser.setText('Hello there!')
```

Better, but not wonderful: it's just 3 characters, but it really doesn't provide a lot of benefits. Also, it really doesn't make a lot of sense to have objects that are direct children of `self.log_widget` but are only accessible through `self.log_widget.ui`.

The more common and suggested approach is the multiple inheritance method, which allows to always have direct access to the objects. The only downside is that even for simple widgets and dialogs you *always need* to create a subclass.

```
class LogWidget(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)


class Application(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Application, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # ...

        self.log_widget = LogWidget()
        self.log_widget.textBrowser.setText('hello there!')
        self.log_widget.exec_()
```

As you can see, it works almost in the same way, except from the fact that it's more simple, concise and readable.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to post such a complete and thoughtful answer. I should've thought to subclass the window. Cheers!